# awk: print based on regular expression

Tags: awk, sed

here is my file.txt

```
KJKJJ1KLJKJKJ928482711|PIEJHHKIA|87166188177633|AJHHHH77760|00666667|876876800874|2014100898798789979879877770
```

I want to edit the field `$7` (`2014100898798789979879877770`) and extract only the 8 first characters (`20141008`) and change them to be `08102014`, this is, a date. Then, concatenate them with `000000`: the output of $7 should be `08102014000000`.

here is my code but it changes the first field $1, I want that it changes the field `$7`:

```
sed 's~^\([0-9]\{4\}\)\([0-9]\{2\}\)\([0-9]\{2\}\)[^\|]*~\3\2\1000000~' file.txt > other-file.txt
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this one liner with awk:

```
awk -F'|' '{print substr($7,7,2) substr($7,5,2) substr($7,1,4) "000000"}' myfile.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use some `bash` and `date` to convert the date:

```
while IFS="|" read -r v1 v2 v3 v4 v5 v6 var
do
    new=$(date -d"${var:0:8}" "+%d%m%Y")000000
    printf "%s|%s|%s|%s|%s|%s|%s\n" $v1 $v2 $v3 $v4 $v5 $v6 $new
done < file
```

#### Test

```
$ while IFS="|" read -r v1 v2 v3 v4 v5 v6 var; do new=$(date -d"${var:0:8}" "+%d%m%Y")000000; printf "%s|%s|%s|%s|%s|%s|%s\n" $v1 $v2 $v3 $v4 $v5 $v6 $new; done < a
KJKJJ1KLJKJKJ928482711|PIEJHHKIA|87166188177633|AJHHHH77760|00666667|876876800874|08102014000000
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have `gawk` try

```
awk '{$NF=gensub(/(....)(..)(..)(.*)/,"\\3\\2\\1000000","g",$NF)}1' OFS='|' FS='|' file
```

Answer (score 1):

if you have Gnu awk, you can use the `gensub()` function:

```
awk -F'|' -v OFS="|" '{$7=gensub(/(....)(..)(..).*/,"\\3\\2\\1000000","g",$7)}7' file
```

with your example, it outputs:

```
KJKJJ1KLJKJKJ928482711|PIEJHHKIA|87166188177633|AJHHHH77760|00666667|876876800874|08102014000000
```

Answer (score 0):

Perl solution:

```
 perl -aF'\|' -lne 'print join "|", @F[ 0 .. 5 ],
                          substr($F[6], 6, 2) . substr ($F[6], 4, 2) . substr($F[6], 0, 4) . 0 x 6;'
```

To correctly handle the date, you can use `Time::Piece`:

```
perl -MTime::Piece -aF'\|' \
  -lne 'print join "|", @F[0..5],
                        Time::Piece->strptime(substr($F[6], 0, 8), "%Y%m%d")->dmy(q()) . 0 x 6;'
```

Answer (score 0):

A combination of awk and sed like this:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="|"}{print $7}' file | sed -n 's/\(.\{4\}\)\(.\{2\}\)\(.\{2\}\).*/\3\2\1000000/p'
```